# MySQL Design for User Photo Gallery

Tags: php, mysql, database-design, gallery, photo-gallery

I am working on a database design for a basic photo gallery which each user can upload several images.

Right now here is what I have:

**photo_gallery**

```
photo_id -    image             - sort_order - user_id
1        -    test.jpg          - 1          - 1
2        -    another_photo.jpg - 2          - 1
```

And then on my folder structure I would create a new folder like so:
**images/photo-gallery/**  and store the images in there.  Now, should I create a folder for each user_id and store their specific images in that folder/

So in this case:
**images/photo-gallery/1/test.jpg**   and all of user 1's photos will be there?

Also for re-sizing, I am thinking about using [smart image resizer](http://shiftingpixel.com/2008/03/03/smart-image-resizer/) so I can just store the original photo, and if I want to resize it to a certain size, I can just call it using the script like: /image.php?width=200&height=200&image=test.jpg.

Should I be hashing these file names?  Am I missing anything else?  Any suggestions on how to improve this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Now, should I create a folder for each user_id and store their specific images in that folder?

Yes, it would be a good idea to separate uploads in some way so you don't end up with one directory holding tens of thousands of files. You could separate them by userid, by first letters (e.g. images/t/te/test.jpg), or by hash (e.g. images/0e/0e4fab12.jpg).

---

> Should I be hashing these file names?

It depends on what you're trying to accomplish. Since you're planning to refer to the filenames in a URL, storing the filename with a known set of "safe" characters can be an advantage:

```
image.php?image=c/ca/cat%20farting%20On%20a%20lemon.jpg
 -- vs --
image.php?image=0a/0a1b2c3d.jpg
```

If you do this, however, I would suggest extending your database schema to include the original filename:

```
photo_id | image           | orig_fn           | sort_order | user_id
1        | 0a/0a1b2c3d.jpg | charginLazors.jpg | 1          | 2
```

You might also consider storing additional metadata about the image, such as the upload date, a caption, etc.

---

Regarding the folder structure, you can use any number of characters from the filename, though there are some things to consider:

Using a hashing method that creates hexadecimal filenames means your maximum number of subfolders will be a multiple of 16:

- One character — 16 subfolders
- Two characters — 256 subfolders
- Three characters — 4096 subfolders

If you use more than two characters, I'd suggest nesting the folders even further: `0a/0a12/0a12bd31.jpg` *-or-* `0a/12/0a12bd31.jpg`. This makes navigating/managing the files a bit more manageable (IMO)

Keep in mind that the more prefixed characters you use, the less files will be in each folder. If you're expecting high volume, you might choose to have more folders with less files per folder.

Comment: This is a good answer. I just wanted to highlight the possibility of filename/filepath duplication. If there is any possibility that a user will upload an image of the same name OR that users will upload the same image (in the case that you are basing the filename on a hash of the image itself) you need to make sure that you're first checking for duplication (file_exists()) and handling it in some way. You might also append the mysql photo_id to the end of the file ('_'.photo_id) to keep it unique and also possibly use it as an identifying shortcut in the future.

Comment: Thanks for a great answer.  Just a couple of questions.  For storing the path, wouldn't it be best to store it as: 0a/0a1b2c3d.jpg instead of including the images folder, in case I ever change it?  And also what would the benefit be, in this situation for storing the original file name?

Comment: @Drew: Good catch. Yes, it would be better to store the image path in the database relative to your image root path (which you might set in a configuration file). I'll revise the answer. Regarding the original filename, it really depends on the purpose of the gallery. If it would be useful for the user to view the original filename of the image (or, to download the image with its original name rather than a seemingly random name), then include it. If the filename is irrelevant, skip it. That's the beauty of building your own system: you can make it suit your intended use perfectly.

Comment: ok awesome, thanks!  and one last question.  I would create a PHP script that would re-name the file to a hash, and automatically grab the first 2 letters and create a folder for it if it does not exist?  wouldn't there be a LOT of folders since if it's randomly generated, the odds of each file having the same 2 letters as a previous one are slim?  or am I misunderstanding something?

Comment: Yes, you will generate the hash in your upload handler, create any necessary folders on your image path, and then use [`move_uploaded_file()`](http://www.php.net/manual/function.move-uploaded-file.php) to put it in its final location with the hashed filename. I've also updated the answer with a better explanation of folder structure possibilities.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation.  Yeah I don't expect a lot of images at all, couple hundred at max. So I don't think nesting the folders even more would be necessary.

Answer (score 0):

> Now, should I create a folder for each user_id

That's a pretty good solution, another possibility is to create a folder per year and eventually per month depending one the targeted number of photos.
For the photo filename I advise to use the database id this will keep you away from character encoding issues and eventually keep the original name in the database.

> Also for re-sizing, I am thinking about using smart image resizer

For my point of view, unless you need to keep the full size image, I suggest to store resized photos. The benefits are the following: you can store more photos, you can send photos more rapidly, the photo navigation will be more reactive.

> Am I missing anything else?

Well maybe the kind of user permission that could drive the way you store images.

> Any suggestions on how to improve this?

I worked on these ideas and created a PhotoBlog that you can find [here](http://javalikescript.free.fr/project/pb/) it's open source so feel free to throw a look in the PHP and JavaScript source code.